# Base de données ou base des données ?

Tags: pluriel, déterminants

Je suis étudiant en Français Langue Étrangère.
J'ai une question par rapport à l'utilisation de *de* et *des*.

J'ai remarqué que parfois la règle « de + quelque chose au pluriel » n'est pas forcément appliquée.

Exemple : « Base de données » au lieu de « Base des données ».
Je n'ai pas d'autres exemples à vous donner mais j'espère que quelqu'un peut m'aider à expliquer cette énigme !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La différence entre *de* et *des*  dans des cas comme celui que tu exposes est la caractéristique déterminée ou indéterminée des objets en question. Je m'explique :

Dans « *nom* des *noms* », *des* est la contraction de *de* et *les*. Il sous-entend donc que les objets ou personnes sont spécifiques, tandis que lorsque *de* est utilisé, on fait référence à quelque chose en général.

Si on prend ton exemple, une *base de données* est une base qui contient des données quelconques. Par contre, la *base des données* est la base qui contient des données précises, connues, par exemple d'une entreprise.

> Cette base de données est la base des données financières de l'entreprise.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication. Donc c'est pour la même raison que c'est **Laboratoire d'analyses** et pas **Laboratoire des analyses**?

Comment: @user1277033 Oui, effectivement.

Comment: Merci à vous. L'énigme est résolu =)

Comment: @afiqjohari Ce fut un plaisir. Si une réponse est celle que vous cherchiez à une question, n'oubliez pas de l'accepter comme bonne réponse en cliquant sur le chrochet à gauche!

Comment: C'est fait comme vous suggériez.