# When to use “du” instead of “des”?

Tags: grammaire, articles, pluriel, partitif

I don't understand why people sometimes use 'du' instead of 'des' when the meaning of both articles is the same.
For example, "some pencils" is *des crayons* whereas "some cheese" is *du fromage*.

Comment: It's all about what they call in French "l'article partitif."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use *du* (masculine) or *de la* (feminine) followed by a singular noun for uncountable quantities. Use *des* followed by plural for countable ones.

Examples:

> Du bonheur.
>   De la patience.
>   Des amis et des amies.

Some nouns can be both uncountable and countable:

> De la bière.
>   Des bières. (*Note: might stand for several beer cans, or several beer sorts.*)

---

Note: *du* or *de la* don't always denote uncountable quantities, as *de* is a widely used preposition in French.

> Ils parlent de la pluie et du beau temps.

If you would like to use an indefinite quantity following a *de* preposition simply use *de* + singular (uncountable) or *de* + plural (countable), without an additional article. Examples:

> Ils parlent de bonheur.
>   Ils parlent d'amis.

Note that using “du bonheur” (the general notion) would mean something different from “de bonheur” (some subset of the general notion). Same for “de l'ami” (the friend, i.e. a specific friend), “des amis” (all of them), or “d'un ami” (one of them); all are different from “d'amis” (some of them).

Answer (score 10):

Some of the most difficult words in a language are articles and prepositions. The words *du* and *des* can combine a preposition with an article, so it's inevitable that this can get a little complicated.

The word *du* is always a contraction of *de le*. The corresponding feminine form is *de la*, and we use *de l'* for the masculine when it's followed by a vowel. The plural is *des*. Then, to complicate matters:

- In *de la* and the others, the word *de* can either be the [preposition *de*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Preposition_6) (which has many meanings; the English preposition “of” is often close), or the first part of the [partitive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_article#Partitive_article) [*du/de la/de l'/des*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Article_2).
- The word *des* can not only be the plural partitive article or the preposition *de* run together with the definite article *les*, but also the plural [indefinite article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/des#Article_2) (plural of *un*).

In your example sentence, *du* is a partitive article. *Du fromage* is the singular form, and *des fromages* is the plural form.

The singular form *du fromage* uses *fromage* as an [uncountable noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). “*Je mange du fromage*”: “I'm eating cheese” (or “I'm eating some cheese” or “I eat cheese”; French doesn't normally distinguish between these). The singular is used because cheese is a substance, and I'm eating an indeterminate amount of that substance. Contrast:

- *Je mange du fromage*. (I'm eating some cheese now.)
- *Je mange des fromages à pâte dure.* (I eat hard cheeses. The plural is used because *fromage* here means “a type of cheese”.)
- *Je mange du riz.* (I'm eating rice. Rice is uncountable.)
- *Je mange des pommes de terre.* (I'm eating potatoes. You can count potatoes, so we use the plural — even if the potatoes happen to be in the form of *purée*, i.e. mashed potatoes.)
- *Je bois du thé.* (I drink tea.)
- *J'ai bu trois thés aujourd'hui.* (I've drunk three teas today, i.e. three cups of tea.)
- *Je préfère les thés peu fermentés.* (I prefer teas (i.e. varieties of tea) that are lightly oxidized.)

See also [Usage of “d'eau” vs “de l'eau”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/usage-of-deau-vs-de-leau). To complicate matters even further, sometimes the plural is *de* instead of *des* — see [Elle a de/des longs cheveux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux), [Base de données ou base des données ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/base-de-donnees-ou-base-des-donnees).

Comment: Maybe one day we should consider a blog post with the full story :-)

Comment: @gilles, I know this is an old answer but in order to add clarification you should consider updating the first translation of "Je mange du fromage", I think you meant "I eat cheese".

Comment: @mmontoya I meant to write what I wrote, but you're right, it can also mean ”I eat cheese“ (as in: “je ne suis pas intolérant au lactose, je mange du fromage”). But I was thinking of the more common situation “I'm eating cheese right now”.

Answer (score 5):

Jez' answers misses a crucial point, I'm afraid: **you can say *des fromages*!**

The distinction is simply between [mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) (which allow the use of *de* with a singular) and [count nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) (which don't). You can say *Je veux des crayons* (in which *des* **does not** mean "of the") because you can use that with almost all French nouns (there are very French words that are not count nouns in at least some meanings), but you can hardly say *je veux du crayon* because *crayon* is not a mass noun (vs. *la mine du/des crayons*, "the pencil's/pencils' lead")

The distinction is only troublesome to English speakers because English drop articles for both mass nouns and count nouns (compare *I'm eating cake/cakes* and *je mange du/des gateaux*, which make exactly the same distinction).

Answer (score 3):

The preposition *de* can be very difficult [French word](https://www.rosettastone.com/french-words), even at advanced levels.

> de is "of" and a bunch of other things
>
> du = de + le
>
> des= de + les
>
> du, de la de l', and des all directly translate to "of the" however
>   they have other uses.

Unspecified quantities represent the notion of “some” in English, but we don’t always use the word “some.” When you are talking about a portion of one item (food, like "some bread"), or something that cannot be quantified (quality, like "some patience"), use what the French call "a partitive article."

Answer (score 2):

Use du (masculine) or de la (feminine) followed by a sing. noms for articles indéfinis(uncountable) while des followed by plural noms for article définis(countable).

example of articles indéfinis

> Masculine 
>   sing. UN livre
>   plur. DES livres
>
> Feminine
>   sing. UNE table
>   plur. DES tables

example for articles définis

> Masculine
>   sing. LE livre
>   plur. LES livres
>
> Feminine
>   sing. LA table
>   plur. LES tables

Answer (score 0):

Use *du* when the object of the sentence is singular.  *du* is short for *de le*, and *des* is short for *de les*, so:

> Il vient du jardin.
>   Je voudrais du gâteau.
>   Je voudrais des pommes.

In your examples, *crayons* is plural (so *des* is used) whereas *fromage* is singular (so *du* is used).

Comment: So des crayons literally means 'of the crayons' and not 'some crayons'?

Comment: Yes, in French, they use "of the" to mean "some".