# Quelle est la différence entre « petits » et « petites » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, genre

What are the differences between:

1. *petites* and *petits*
2. *grandes* and *grands*

---

Quelle sont les différences entre :

1. *petites* et *petits*
2. *grandes* et *grands*

Comment: Only one question at a time. The third item wasn't related to the first two. You may ask about it in a separate post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Petit** and **petite** are adjectives. They are both the same word. *Petit* is used as a qualifier for "small", or "little", in the masculine form. *Petite* is used in the feminine form. The **s** is used for the plural form. The same goes for **grandes** and **grand**. *Grandes* is a plural/feminine qualifier and *grands* is masculin/plural.

For **des filles** and **de filles** it is a little bit different. You use *des filles* when you want to say *girl* in the plural form. For example: Il y a des filles dans mon cour de math. - There are girls in my math class.

*De fille* is used as a qualifier. For example: des films de filles - Girly movies.

Other example : These are games for girls. Ce sont des jeux de filles. (qualifies the game as being girly) **vs**  I played these games with girls. - J'ai joué à ces jeux avec des filles.

---

**Petit** et **petite** sont des adjectifs. Ce sont les mêmes mots. *Petit* et utilisé comme qualificatif pour la forme au masculin et *petite* pour le féminin. Le *s* est utilisé pour le pluriel. C'est la même chose pour **grandes** et **grands**. *Grandes** est pluriel/féminin et *grands* est pluriel/masculin.

Pour **des filles** et **de filles**, c'est différent. On utilise *des filles* quand l'on veut utiliser **fille** au pluriel. *De filles* est un qualificatif.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please give me another example of 'de'? Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @birajrai De/des can be several things depending on the context. See http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/usage-of-deau-vs-de-leau, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/base-de-donnees-ou-base-des-donnees, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/are-de-la-biere-and-de-biere-both-acceptable, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/difference-entre-nom-de-article-nom-et-nom-de-nom-quand-mett, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/parler-de-un-article-partitif-ou-larticle-indefini-des, …

Comment: *Petit* et *petites* peuvent également être des noms communs.